# KnockoutJS fromJS not working TypeError: Cannot call method 'fromJS' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I use knockoutJS and i had the following error when i use "fromJS"

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'fromJS' of undefined

**My JavaScript Code**

```
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var PersonModel = function (data) {
             ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
         };

         var data = $.getJSON("http://localhost:40913/candidate/index/1", function (data)
         {
             viewModel = new PersonModel(data);
             ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
         }
         );
     });
 </script>
```

**JSON Output**

> ```
> {
> PersonalInfo: {
> PTitle: null,
> PGender: {
> Id: 1,
> Name: "Male",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> PMilitaryService: {
> Id: 2,
> Status: "Exempted",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> PMarital: {
> Id: 2,
> Status: "Engaged",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> PNationality: {
> Id: 1,
> NationalityName: "Egyptian",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> Id: 1,
> FirstName: "Jason",
> SecondName: "J",
> ThirdName: "Patrick",
> FourthName: "Jules",
> BirthDate: "2013-01-01T00:00:00",
> GenderId: 1,
> MilitaryServiceId: 2,
> MaritalId: 2,
> NationalityId: 1,
> IsDeleted: null,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T13:32:20.437",
> ModifiedBy: null,
> FullName: "fhfghfghfghgfhg"
> },
> TraineeInfo: null,
> AdressInfo: {
> PCity: {
> Id: 6,
> Name: "Cairo",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> PCountry: {
> Id: 1,
> Name: "France",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> Id: 1,
> Street: "5th Ave",
> District: "6th Area",
> CityId: 6,
> CountryId: 1,
> IsDeleted: null,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T13:32:20.437",
> ModifiedBy: null
> },
> ContactInfo: {
> Id: 1,
> PhoneNumber: "12345678",
> MobileNumber: "2012415413",
> Email: "a@b.com",
> EmailConfirm: null,
> IsDeleted: null,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T13:32:20.437",
> ModifiedBy: null
> },
> HighSchool: {
> PSchoolCertificate: {
> Id: 1,
> Name: "Thanwya Amma",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> Id: 1,
> Name: "El Nasr School",
> SchoolCertificateId: 1,
> GraduationYear: "2013-01-10T00:00:00",
> OverallGrade: 90,
> OtherSchoolCertificate: null,
> IsDeleted: null,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T13:32:20.437",
> ModifiedBy: null
> },
> Type: {
> Id: 1,
> Type: "Fresh Graduate",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> Certifications: [ ],
> TrainingCourses: [ ],
> CareerHistories: [ ],
> Universities: [
> {
> PCertificate: {
> Id: 1,
> CertificateType: "BACHELOR",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> PUniversityName: {
> Id: 2,
> Name: "ABBASSIA",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> PFaculty: {
> Id: 1,
> Name: "ACCOUNTING",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> PSpecialization: {
> Id: 2,
> Name: "ACCOUNTING ENGLISH",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> PGrade: {
> Id: 3,
> OverallGrade: "Very Good",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> Id: 1,
> CertificateId: 1,
> OtherCertificate: null,
> UniversityNameId: 2,
> OtherUniversity: null,
> FacultyId: 1,
> OtherFaculty: null,
> SpecializationId: 2,
> OtherSpecialization: null,
> GraduationYear: "2013-01-04T00:00:00",
> GradeId: 3,
> IsDeleted: null,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T13:32:20.437",
> ModifiedBy: null
> }
> ],
> Languages: [
> {
> PLangName: {
> Id: 1,
> Name: "English",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> PLangProf: {
> Id: 4,
> LanguageProf: "Native",
> IsDeleted: false,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T00:00:00",
> ModifiedBy: "System Auto Generated"
> },
> Id: 1,
> LangNameId: 1,
> LangProfId: 4,
> IsDeleted: null,
> LastModified: null,
> ModifiedBy: null
> }
> ],
> TestInfo: null,
> InterviewInfo: null,
> TechnicalInterview: null,
> MedicalTest: null,
> SecuirtyTest: null,
> HREmployee: null,
> Id: 1,
> Ssid: "28454654654545",
> SsidConfirm: null,
> Status: null,
> StatusId: 1,
> RefCode: "8951000000",
> ApplicationTypeId: 1,
> EntryDate: "2013-01-21T13:32:20.437",
> Skills: "aaksdklasdjkl asd asd d d d g ghs fgdsfgd",
> Photo: null,
> IsDeleted: null,
> LastModified: "2013-01-21T13:32:20.437",
> ModifiedBy: null
> }
> ```

Comment: Are you not loading the Knockout mapping plugin? I see it's missing from your references...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Get the plugin from

```
https://raw.github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.js
```

and add it via:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Solved the problem ... Thanks