# Knockout JS Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromJS' in Oracle Cloud

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I am getting this error in Knockout.js:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromJS' of undefined

I am new to Knockout JS.I am developing Knockout JS in Oracle Content and Experience Cloud. My scenario is I am trying to call Rest API and get the results and display it in table.

I am using below REST API url to test in my application
http://learn.knockoutjs.com/mail?folder=inbox

Below is my code:

```
/* globals define */
define(['knockout', 'jquery', 'text!./knockout.mapping-latest.js', 'text!./mailbox.json', 'css!./css/design.css'], function (ko, $, mapping, css) {
    'use strict';
    // ----------------------------------------------
    // Define a Knockout Template for your component
    // ----------------------------------------------
    var sampleComponentTemplate = 
        '<div>' + 
        '<p><input data-bind="value: searchValue" class="box"/></p>' +
        '<button data-bind="click: getCustomers">Knock out Search</button>' +
        '</div>' +  
        '<table>' +
            '<thead>' +
                '<tr>' +                
                    '<th>From</th>' + 
                    '<th>To</th>' + 
                    '<th>Subject</th>' + 
                    '<th>Date</th>' + 
                '</tr>' + 
            '</thead>' + 
            '<tbody data-bind="foreach: mails">' + 
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td data-bind="text: from"></td>' +  
                    '<td data-bind="text: to"></td>' + 
                    '<td data-bind="text: subject"></td>' + 
                    '<td data-bind="text: date"></td>' +                    
                '</tr>' +
            '</tbody>' + 
        '</table>';



// ----------------------------------------------
    // Define a Knockout ViewModel for your template
    // ----------------------------------------------
    var SampleComponentViewModel = function (args) {
    this.searchValue = ko.observable("Hi");

 this.mails = ko.observableArray();    
  this.getCustomers = function () {     
    alert("Inside get customers ");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',             
            crossDomain: true, 
            url: 'documents/folder/F49A137E34CB4B6DFD302FB90A04F4D8CA1E8A3D5B3E/_assets/mailbox.json',
            data: JSON.stringify(this.mails),             
            success: function(data) {           
                var observableData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
                var array = observableData();
                this.mails(array);

            },
            error:function(jq, st, error){
                alert("Inside Error Method " + error + " jq is " + jq + "st is " + st);
            }
        });
    };

    };
```

Comment: Please note that `Please correct my code as well if there are any mistakes` is a request for free labour. Readers are willing to _help_ you, but not do your work for you. We get hundreds of people every day expecting too much of volunteers, and it is good to ensure your question does not look like theirs `:-)`.

Comment: So, my immediate response is that there is no `ko.mapping` property in existence in your Ajax success handler's first line.  Have you checked to ensure you are loading all of your KO dependencies properly?  See this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441276/knockoutjs-fromjs-not-working-typeerror-cannot-call-method-fromjs-of-undefine

Comment: Hi Paul, I am loading knockout.mapping-latest.js file in the initialization itself. But somehow fromJS is not recognized. I even tried with mapping.fromJS also even that did not work

Comment: @Rajesh - try changing `ko.mapping.fromJS(data)` to `mapping.fromJS(data)`.  You may need to make that change, as it appears you are attaching the mapping Knockout plugin to `mapping`.

Comment: @Paul you are correct I am mapping knockout plugin to mapping even if I try with mapping.fromJS(data).
 
Still I am getting error as following
 Uncaught TypeError: mapping.fromJS is not a function

Comment: I solved it by initializing self =this, and replacing this in the code with self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by initializing self =this, and replacing this in the code with self